# Time zones with and without DST in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

The more I read up on this, the more confused I get.

My plan for a project is to handle all date/time storage and calculation in UTC except when it comes to displaying that data. The problem is that the server will move to different locations with different time zone and daylight savings time information, so I'll have to implement some form of time zone selector in the UI.

But there's all kinds of exceptions to where DST happens and where it doesn't, e.g. Arizona has no DST except for the Navajo Indian Reservation. So I can't simply use the PHP list of time zone locations (e.g. 'America/Phoenix') since I don't know if the actual location of the server will be in such an area, so I'm guessing I'll have to implement a checkbox saying "Use Daylight Savings Time" and a more basic select box with simple time zone information, e.g. "CST -6" etc.

I could use the 'America/Phoenix' system to display a list of cities, but that would result in a really long list. But if I use EST/CST in my list, it won't be accurate for areas with vs. without DST, so I don't think I can do this without the "DST?" checkbox.

However, I just tried PHP's `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` with 'CST', 'CDT', and 'CST6CDT', and all three result in the same time, both for a date in February and a date in June. I figured, CDT should be with DST, CST should be without DST, and CST6CDT should use automatic switching, but apparently it's not that simple...

So ... if I am using a list of time zones like EST/CST/PST etc. and want the ability to turn off DST via a checkbox, how would I implement that in the PHP code? How can I tell PHP to convert the time to the correct time zone WITH support for turning DST on or off?

I know the basic code for this, but not how to change DST:

```
$myTime = new DateTime('02/10/2013 08:00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($myTime);  // UTC
$localTz = new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix');  // selected by user
$myTime->setTimezone($localTz);
var_dump($myTime);  // Phoenix with local DST settings
```

On a different but related note, does changing the location of a Linux server cause the server's internal clock to change time zones? Will moving the server mess up the internal clock and result in incorrect UTC timestamps?

Comment: If the server moves around, even more reason to use UTC *always* and let JavaScript do the heavy lifting :)

Comment: As I said, I'll use UTC for everything until it needs to be displayed. But I've heard enough warnings about JavaScript and timezones to not even bother with it, and I don't need it to be interactive - just displayed.

Comment: system clocks on linux servers tend to be kept in UTC, then converted to local at displaytime.

Comment: @MarcB OK, then the question is how the server determines where (i.e. in what timezone) it is located at displaytime or when it tells its time to PHP... When I use `DateTime` with "now" in PHP, which time does the Linux server give it? Should be the local time and not UTC, right?

Comment: I've never heard of such warnings, because it doesn't even have to handle timezones, just one; that said, basically your question is how to best populate the interface for users?

Comment: @semmelbroesel: ubuntu: /etc/timezone. redhat: /etc/sysconfig/clock. the server's localtime zone is generally prompted for at install time, just like on pretty much every other OS (e.g. Windows prompts for this info as well...)

Comment: @MarcB The timezone PHP uses is inside the `.ini` though :)

Comment: No, I can come up with a static UI with a dropdown for PST/MST/CST etc. and a checkbox. The problem is: Once I have this information, especially the "turn on DST" checkbox, how do I implement this into PHP code that will use my internal UTC timestamp and convert it into local time based on the selected timezone AND the selected UTC setting?

Comment: @jack: php will use system default unless you overrride it with the .ini setting.

Comment: @MarcB OK, so I'll probably set the Linux timezone to UTC if I can - I just heard something from one of our Linux guys that the server will use its IP address to figure out where it is and adjust its time and/or timezone automatically ... I could be wrong on this, obviously :-)

Comment: @MarcB Well yeah, if you ignore the warning that you see when using `date()` related functions ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you describe has been done before, and always has the same problems:

- Most users aren't smart enough to know whether to check the box or not.
- It doesn't make sense to even have the box, since the time zone rules have all the details of whether or not DST applies, when it applies, and by how much.
- Time zone abbreviations are ambiguous.  For example, without any other information, how do you know that `CST` means US Central Standard Time?  It might mean China Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time.  There is a list [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/) that illustrates all of the variations.
- There isn't always agreement about what the abbreviation should be.  For example, is Hawaii in HST or HAST?

It is always best to use the actual IANA time zone identifier, such as `America/Phoenix` or `America/Los_Angeles`.  If you need an easier way for your users to pick the correct time zone, try a map-based picker, such as [this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).

To clarify your concerns about the operating system time zone affecting PHP.

- If you just say `new DateTime()`, then yes - it will pick up the default time zone.  This can be *changed* with a call to [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), but the initial setting comes out of the `date.timezone` setting in the php.ini file, or from the `TZ` environment variable of the OS.
- It's always better to be explicit about the time zone, so you are not affected by any of these defaults.

  For example, to get the current time in Phoenix:

  ```
  new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'))
  ```

  To get it in UTC:

  ```
  new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'))
  ```
- You can use UTC where it makes sense, but it is not a mandate.  Where it matters most is when you save/retrieve from the database, or when transmitting across an api, web service, etc.
- If you are always explicit, then the time zone of the server doesn't really matter.  Linux will sync the system bios to UTC regardless of the time zone.  Windows will sync the bios with local time, but has some internals such that you can always get the correct UTC time still. (rather ugly, but works).
- But still, it is a "best practice" to set servers to UTC time zone.  The main reason is so that you find out early that you have time-zone dependent code.  (The worst time to find out is in the middle of the night during a DST transition you didn't plan for.)

Comment: Ooh, I like this map-based picker - that'll definitely keep the interface simpler, thanks! OK, I don't know enough about time zones really, so if this is a stupid question, please let me know: If for some reason the server would end up on the reservation in Arizona (i.e. in a state without DST but a location inside the state that does follow DST), what then? I don't know how many of these exceptions exist in the US...

Comment: It doesn't matter where your server is deployed or what it's operating system time zone is set to, as long as you never ask the server for the "local" time.  You can use UTC, or you can use a named time zone.  But don't just say "now".  And regarding that specific zone, there is `America/Shiprock` that covers the Navajo reservation.

Comment: Oh, never noticed that reservation time zone - thanks! One more question to clear things up, though: "as long as you never ask the server for the 'local' time" - how do I get the current time in UTC then?

Comment: See my answer, I show how to get the current time in Phoenix, and also how to get the current time in UTC.

Comment: Great, thanks so much! The combination of suggestions you wrote should do the job :-)

Answer (score 3):

As somebody who spent 13 months working on a major refactor revolving around this, I can tell you: you *must* store **user intent time** and then decode that to **viewer local time**.

What I mean by "user intent time" is the combination of the time and the user's time zone. As DST changes, you will need to use *both* pieces of information to decode what time to display for a user from a different location.  I don't just mean when spring and fall changeovers happen - I mean when governments change the DST laws and the Olson tzdata database is updated.

You do have a cron job to update tzdata from PECL often, right? :)

You'll want to use - and likely extend - PHP's buggy DateTime and DateTimeZone builtins.  They're your only hope.

Comment: Oh, it's quite the pain in the neck for sure :-) There's so much stuff we SHOULD be doing, and this cron job is one of them :-/ Eventually, we'll have to have every user pick their time zone and store that in their information. I already have started storing times as UTC in our database for some parts.

Comment: When it comes to searching and sorting in the database, we had the user intent data (their timezone and their local time) and then we had UTC fields as well - periodically, we had to go through with another cron job and update UTC times from user intent data if it was indicating something in the present or future - since as time zones change, the UTC data becomes incorrect.